# How to find the position of the first non-NA element in a column starting with the last element in an xts object

Tags: r, xts

```
> vols
               vol_tr     vol_yz     vol_cl    vol_iv
2021-01-22 0.06260922 0.09798388 0.09861034        NA
2021-01-25 0.09783596 0.10595096 0.10121109 0.1362547
2021-01-26 0.10485836 0.10672985 0.10117991 0.1388527
2021-01-27 0.08284200 0.10742612 0.09586469 0.1509771
2021-01-28 0.08452010 0.11046722 0.10247347 0.1229756
2021-01-29 0.07045891 0.11292108 0.10991404        NA
```

I'd like to find the index of the first non-NA in column vols$vol_iv starting at the end of the column. I'm looking for index or position 5. To find the first non-NA from *beginning* I can do:

```
> d <- coredata(vols$vol_iv)
> pos = Position(function(d)!is.na(d), d)
> pos
[1] 2
```

`Position` is nice b/c it only evaluates until a match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim the NA's off the right end using `na.trim` and then take the length of that to find the position (or use `end` in place of `length` if you want the time of the last non-NA value).

```
library(xts)

x <- xts(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA), as.Date("2000-01-01")+0:5) # test input

length(na.trim(x, sides = "right"))
## [1] 5
```

To get the positions of both the start and end at the same time or just use `rng` if you want the times instead.

```
rng <- range(time(na.trim(x)))
match(rng, time(x))
## [1] 2 5
```